# Javascript: How to use the reduce function and the concat array function to transform an array of arrays into an array?

Tags: javascript, concatenation, reduce

Javascript: How to use the reduce function and the concat array function to transform an array of arrays into an array?

In the following code, the array of arrays is not transformed and the browser console log logs an empty array.

Under the code below, what is the exact reason for the failure?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
  // use reduce to transform an array of 
  // arrays to one array that combines all.
  // elements.

  function combine(array1d, element)
  {
    array1d.concat(element);

    return array1d;
  }

  function reduce(array2d, combine) {

    let array1d = [];

    for (let element of array2d) {

      array1d = combine(array1d, element);

    }

    return array1d;
  }

  let array2d =  [[1, 2,],[3, 4]];
  console.log(reduce(array2d, combine));
```

Comment: The result should be `[1, 2, 3, 4]`?

Comment: Yes, definitely it should be `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Comment: Instead of `array1d = combine(array1d, element);` you could do `array1d = array1d.concat(element);` (making `combine` obsolete)

Comment: maybe you want to learn about spread operator const combinedarray = [...ar1, ...ar2]

Comment: Under the code above, what is the actual reason for the failure?

Comment: Ciao, the element that you concat is not a single number but it's an array and the result is an array of 2 array.

Comment: Browser console says the return is an empty array: `Array []`.

Comment: Take a look at my answer. I posted a snippet that works!

Comment: Right, your answer is nice, however, I really would like to know the reason why the above code does not work? Is is a logic error, or specific misuse of some property?

Comment: Ah, maybe now I see the error: concat returns an array so you have to do `array1d = array1d.concat(element)`. Try this.

Comment: `concat` doesn't mutate the array, it creates a new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see by all the answers, there are multiple ways to do this.

1. One solution which is fixing the error in the original question:

```
function combine(array1d, element) {
  return array1d.concat(element);
}

function reduce(array2d, reducerFn) {
  let array1d = [];

  for (let element of array2d) {
    array1d = reducerFn(array1d, element);
  }

  return array1d;
}

let array2d =  [[1, 2,],[3, 4]];
console.log(reduce(array2d, combine));
```

The difference here is the `return array1d.concat(element);` call instead of returning `array1d` and call `.concat` on it. [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) is side-effect free, so it creates a new array instead of mutating the original one. I've also renamed `combine` in `reduce` to `reducerFn` to make it more clear that it could be changed to something else.

2. Using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) directly on the array (supported by almost all browsers)

```
let result = array2d.reduce(function (flattenedArray, element) {
  return flattenedArray.concat(element);
}, []);
```

3. Using `reduce` and the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) instead of `concat` (no IE support - if you can drop it, you can also use [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)):

```
let result = array2d.reduce(function (flattenedArray, element) {
  return [...flattenedArray, ...element];
}, []);
```

4. Using [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap), the identity function can be used to flatten the array:

```
let result = array2d.flatMap(element => element);
```

5. Using [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat), which flattens (deeply) nested arrays the amount of dimensions it receives as an argument:

```
let result = array2d.flat();
```

6. Using imperative style by creating a for loop for each dimension, fill the array in order - see answer by

`flatMap` and `reduce`, like `concat`, also return a new array, without mutating the original one. Since the original version looked more like trying to use a functional programming style to me, I guess these are a good addition to your toolbox. `flatMap` and `flat` are relatively recent additions to the language, so depending on the environments you need to support, you might end up using something else instead.

Comment: Not sure where the typo is...? The `combine` function is a parameter for `reduce` - it could be switched to something completely different, like summing up the numbers instead of concatenating.

Comment: Think of having `function combineMax(array1d, element) { return array1d.concat([Math.min(...element)]); }`. You could use `reduce(array2d, combineMin)` and get the minimum values of each of the nested arrays. That's why I think the parameter does not have to be named `combine` but can be generalised to the `reducerFn`

Comment: Yes, as soon as there is a parameter in a function, the outer variable / function / constant / whatever will be shadowed by that parameter. That means even if the parameter is called `combine`, `reduce` might call some completely different function, depending on how `reduce` is being called

Answer (score 1):

You can transform the 2D array into an array first with `flat`, and then use the `reduce` function to add the elements.

If you don't need to add the elements, just remove the `reduce`.

```
var res = array2d.flat().reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, here working example:

```js
let array2d =  [[1, 2,],[3, 4]];
let result = array2d.flat(1);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const res = array2d.reduce((arr, seq) => {
  arr.push(...seq);
  return arr;
}, [])
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it the old fashioned way?

```
function mergeArray(array){
    let finalArray= []
    for(let i=0;i<iarray.lenght;i++){
          for(let j=0;j<array[i].lenght;j++){
                 finalArray.push(array[i][j])
          }
    }
    return finalArray
}
```